# PgAgent unable to run a job

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pgadmin, pgagent

I am running PostgreSQL 9.4.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.3. I am trying to set up [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/pgagent.html) job but I keep getting this error:

```
DEBUG: Creating DB connection: user=xxx host=localhost port=5432 dbname=otherdb password=pass
DEBUG: Allocating new connection to database 
DEBUG: Executing SQL step 7 (part of job 3)
*** Caught unhandled unknown exception; terminating
DEBUG: Destroying job thread for job 3
```

I have a `.pgpass` file in `xxx`'s user home folder with following content:

```
localhost:5432:*:xxx:pass
```

I tried to run `pgadmin` (as user `xxx`) with this command:

```
pgagent -f -l2 host=localhost dbname=postgres user=xxx password=pass port=5432
```

And the job which I set up is a simple, one-step job which should just print out the PostgreSQL version (the exact command I put in my step is `SELECT version();`) but note that it should run on a different database than defined in `pgagent` command.

I tried to change the connection string of job's step from 'local' (and just selecting `otherdb` from the dropdown menu) to 'remote' (and specifying all the parameters in a connection string manually - `user=xxx host=localhost port=5432 dbname=otherdb password=pass`) but I always see that same error. User `xxx` has all the privileges on both `postgres` and `otherdb` databases.

I am aware that there [was a bug in previous versions of pgAgent](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgagent.git;a=commitdiff;h=f9bf1ccb27ebcfce00e7a6d467bc0e1b5ee9555e) but the version I was using to set up everything was the latest one (3.4.0) so I suppose this might not be related to that issue.

How to figure out what is causing this problem?